# Difference between accesing "on behalf" of a bot vs user

Tags: python, google-sheets, oauth, google-sheets-api, service-accounts

I am working on a program that uses gspread to access a google sheet in python.

On the documentation for gspread, they mention:

> To access spreadsheets via Google Sheets API you need to authenticate and authorize your application.
>
> - If you plan to access spreadsheets *on behalf of a bot* account use Service Account.
> - If you’d like to access spreadsheets *on behalf of end users (including yourself)* use OAuth Client ID.

My understanding is that I am creating a "bot" to access my own account and make changes to a sheet, so I would use OAuth.

Is there some other Google service where bots have their own google sheets, such that accessing said sheets would be accessing "on behalf of" the bot? If not, then what is the difference between these authentication options?

Edit:

It seems the documentation answers part of this question further down:

> A service account is a special type of Google account intended to represent a non-human user that needs to authenticate and be authorized to access data in Google APIs [sic].
>
> Since **it’s a separate account**, by default it does not have access to any spreadsheet until you share it with this account. Just like any other Google account.

The second part to my question still remains-- why would I use the bot option, and what is the difference, provided I am only accessing sheets from one Google user?

Answer (score 1):

Service accounts are accounts that

- used  for server to server interactions
- belong to your application
- uses simplified 2 Legged oauth flow(or  jwt flow) instead of the typical 3 legged flow
- are not used to access end user data but your application specific data

If you create a  android or a python app, You can use a service account(on your hosted server) to act on behalf of that application. This can interact with say, Google sheets(Another server) that are owned/shared  with the service account.  This makes sense because if you use your own account, then end users of your app will  have access to all your Google sheets and other credentials. By using a service account, it'll only have access to the data shared with it/owned by itself.

### References:

- [Server to server interactions](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)
- [Tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/service-accounts/info)